# How can I automate a python code for many cells?

Tags: python, loops, automation, build-automation

I have data for a cell and from these data, I made a python code to extract some parameters. However, I want to repeat the same procedure for 100 cells (that have different initial data/ input). Is there a way to automate the process?

Comment: Please share your code so we can try to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use looping for this.

```
primes = [2, 3, 5, 7]
for prime in primes:
    print(prime)
```